# Read from a .csv file containing exported pcap packet info using Tshark and count particular instances in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to read from a .csv file(created from a .pcap file) and count the no. of instances for certain network packets in python under info column in python. I am using python 2.7 on Windows 7 OS.Is there a way I can do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this  https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
```